# Edit line by line in a file - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a "text inverter". For example, I have different words in a file:

```
hello:world
learning:python
is:funny
```

I would like to revert it to:

```
world:hello
python:learning
funny:is
```

**I have could code the script to reverse the words**, but if the file has more of one line. Example:

```
hello:world
learning:python
```

The script deletes all the other lines and only leaves the first line hello:world. I tried to use `readlines()` function and `\n` but is not working me.

I would like to reverse all the lines that a file can have. =)

Here is the code:

```
#IMPORTS
import os
import platform
import time
import subprocess

#PUT MODULE 2 IN A NEW WINDOW
if platform.system() == "Windows":
    clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
    clear()

#EXPLANATION MODULE SELECTED
print("You selected module two --> Inverter\n")
time.sleep(1) #TIME LOAD

#USER HAVE TO PUT THE FILE NAMED "COMBOS.TXT"
fname = input("Put your file: ")

if fname == "combos.txt":
    try:
        f = open("combos.txt")
        with open("combos.txt", "r") as infile:
            for line in infile:
                words = line.split(":")[::-1]
                final = ":".join(words)
                with open("combos.txt", "w") as out:
                    out.write(final)
                    print("Done!")
    except:
        print("--Something went wrong while trying to load your file--")

input("Your file was edited successfully! Press enter to continue...")
if platform.system() == "Windows":
    p = subprocess.call(["python", "start.py"])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `with open("combos.txt", "w")` will erase the current files content by overwriting it.

You need to either

- write to a different file, delete the original file afterwards and rename your new file, or
- read the whole file into a list/string/whatever, close it and process the data  writing to file freshly created with the same name.

---

```
with open("combos.txt", "r") as infile:
    data = infile.read()

# create a list of lines, removing the \n in the processs
data = data.split("\n")

# this will delete the original file and create it new
with open("combos.txt", "w") as f:
    for line in data: 
        words = line.split(":")[::-1]
        final = ":".join(words)
        # write it and add a \n
        f.write(final+"\n")
```